# How should I store my new Torx screwdriver set?

Tags: tools, storage, hand-tools

I recently bought a 12-piece Wifa Torx screwdriver set, but am not sure how to store it. At first I thought of making a case, but that could be a lot of work and it would have to be deep, like 16 inches, so it could not fit onto a typical 11" shelf.

Another idea is to put them on wall in one of my work areas using terry clips, maybe, but I am not sure how well they will fit into the Terry clips. The screw drivers are a wide variety of sizes so I might need many different sizes of Terry clips if I did this.

The same sizing problem affects other solutions like canvas rollups. Also a rollup with 12 screwdrivers in it will be really fat.

Open to suggestions.

Comment: Is this supposed to be portable ?  Or you are just wanting them at a workbench all the time.  Mine are just tossed in a drawer in a toolbox.

Comment: I would only store them at a work bench. If I had to bring one some where I would put just the one I needed in a bag or tool chest, but for this question I am trying to find a solution for permanent storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a screwdriver holder/organizer?

They come in all shapes and sizes, as well as both wall mount and drawer varieties.

[image: Wall mount screwdriver holder]

[image: Screwdriver organizer]

You could even design and build your own, if you were so inclined.

Comment: Those are interesting racks. What are they?

Comment: This was the first thing that came to my mind. If you want to go the DIY route, a strip of 1x material with holes drilled in it would be really easy to make...as I just realized @ratchet freak suggested in his answer.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this. They sell magnetic strips at the hardware store. You can just screw the strip into the wall near a workbench and the screwdriver adheres to it.

Answer (score 4):

## Tool Belt

[image: Tool Belt]

## Tool Bucket

[image: Tool Bucket]

## Tool Box

[image: Tool Box]

## Tool Chest

[image: Tool Chest]

## Tool Cabinet

[image: Tool Cabinet]

## Tool Truck

[image: Tool Truck]

Comment: This is not really relevant. I want to organize my screw drivers in a convenient way, not throw them in a tool bucket. I do not consider heaping things loose into a rollaway "organized". Toolbox and belts are not for organizing tools. They are for bringing the tools to a work site.

Comment: @TylerDurden In your post you said "*Open to suggestions*", but clearly you are not.

Comment: @TylerDurden ... I guess you haven't seen an anal mechanic before? [Try this on for size](http://www.replicadeusa.com/files/QuickSiteImages/007.JPG).

Comment: @Paulster2 How do you make those shelf inserts?

Comment: That picture of the tool chest with all the drawers open makes me cringe. Good way to end up with all your tools crushing you while you lie on your garage floor trapped under the cabinet.

Comment: @Paulster2 That link sounds like a risky click.

Answer (score 2):

You take a shelf and drill several holes in them. Make sure the holes are too small for the handles to get through. Then just put them shaft down in the holes.

If the shafts are really long then you can add a slot for ease of storage and removal. You may want to add a shallow edge to avoid them slipping out.

[In this video (starting at 1:40)](https://youtu.be/8En-OTfePys?t=1m40s) You can see how simple making one is. you can use a bracket instead of the L shape to keep it steady against the weight.